# How to filter posts, pages, archives and others page?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am developing a new plugin. In this plugin user can choose where the plugin will display.

If user choose only in post or archives pages then how can i find it?
if I use `add_filter('the_content','function');`

then my plugin will show all pages but how to do that in single category or archive page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a specific page is being displayer with these conditonals

```
is_page()   //For pages
is_single   //for posts
is_singular //for posts AND pages
is_category //for categories
is_tag()    //for tags
is_404()    //for 404 page
```

Also, don't use anonymous functions when you add filters. **always** use defined functions

```
add_filter ('the_content','my_magic_function');
```

For a more complete list of template tags check visit:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 0):

We use [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content )
{
    is( !is_single() )
        return $content;

    return '<p>This is a single post.</p>' . $content;
});
```

<sub><sub>*sample code requires PHP 5.3+*</sub></sub>

Comment: single mean post pages only?

Comment: Yes. There are many combinations for those conditionals, you'd have to dig a bit in the documentation to get the ones that are useful in your case.